# Keeping the value of a String initialized into a function

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I know my title isn't clear, It will be clearer with code + examples.
I want to initialize a char* ("motSecret" in the main, "mot" in my function) containing a word selected randomly into a file, doing this into a function. This array is made dynamic using memory allocation.
The variable in my function get well initialized, but when I print the value just after I exited the function, the value change and become something like "0@"

Here is the part concerned in the main :

```
int main()
{
    FILE* dico =NULL;
    char *motSecret, *motRes;
    char lettre=' ';
    int check=0, nbCoups=10, longueur=0, nbMots=0;
    Bool erreur = TRUE;

    srand(time(NULL));
    nbMots = scanDico(dico);
    getWord(dico, nbMots, motSecret);
    printf("Mot : %s", motSecret);
```

The problem appears after the function getWord(). Here is the code of this function :

```
void getWord(FILE* dico, int nbLignes, char *mot)
{
    int numMotChoisi=rand() % nbLignes, nbChar=0;
    char charActuel=' ';

    dico = fopen("dico.txt", "r");
    rewind(dico);
    if(dico != NULL)
    {
        while (numMotChoisi > 0)
        {
            charActuel = fgetc(dico);
            if (charActuel == '\n')
                numMotChoisi--;
        }
        charActuel = ' ';
        while(charActuel != '\n')
        {
            charActuel = fgetc(dico);
            nbChar++;
        }
        fseek(dico,-(nbChar)-1,SEEK_CUR);
        mot = malloc(nbChar * sizeof(char));
        if(mot == NULL)
        {
            printf("Probleme d'allocation memoire");
            exit(0);
        }
        fgets(mot, SIZE, dico);
        mot[strlen(mot) - 1] = '\0';
        printf("Mot = %s ", mot);
    }

    fclose(dico);
}
```

The printf at the end of the function return a good value, and the printf just after the getWord() in the main show that the value changed in the function haven't been "saved"...

Other thing, that works fine without memory allocation.

I hope I'm clear enough. If I forgot to tell something or if you need more informations, please tell me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C uses `pass by value` in function parameter passing.

You need a double pointer, something like `void getWord(FILE* dico, int nbLignes, char **mot)` if you want to allocate memory inside another function.

As a cascased effect, `printf("Mot : %s", motSecret);` is trying to access uninitialized memory, causing undefined behaviour.

Suggestions:

1. I see no reason to use `FILE *dico` as a parameter in `getWord()`. In can very well be a local.
2. instead of using double pointer, i would like to recommend returning the allocated pointer from `getWord()`, i.e., change `void getWord()` to `char * getWord()`, add `return mot` and use like `motSecret = getWord(<params>)`

Comment: As an aside, using return-values is far preferable, if possible.

Comment: @Deduplicator My personal fav, too.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thanks for your answer and your advices, and sorry for late response. I changed my code and it works fine using "return mot" (and also removed the FILE* paramters ;)).
Edit : I'll take a look at the double pointer, don't know it yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *motSecret;
```

`motSecret` is a local variable withing `main()` and it is not initilized.

By calling

```
getWord(dico, nbMots, motSecret);
```

You are passing some uninitialized pointer to a function `getword()`.

Inside `getword()` you are assigning some memory to

```
char *mot;
```

and writing some data to this memory.

Now this memory is not known to `motSecret` You have to return this memory address to the uninitialized pointer in `main()`

```
char *motSecret = getWord(dico, nbMots);
```

Your getword() should be like,

```
char *getWord(dico, nbMots);
```

and inside this after performing everything do,

```
return mot;
```

Comment: Thanks for explanations, it's always usefull to have more details ;)

Comment: @SoJJu np I just wanted to let you know what your code was doing actually

Comment: One thing I don't understand : why do the fgets() function not initalizing my "motSecret" after memory allocation ?
I was using this before allocating memory manually, and it was working oÔ
If my "char* motSecret" is a pointer poiting on the memory address 2500 (purely fictive situation ^^), I send this address to getWord, so "char *mot" should have this address as value. So when using fgets it should act on the address of "motSecret"... I'm missing something ^^